# How to get max value of each column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to get max value for each column of a dataframe in Spark. My code works just for one column (e.g. first):

```
val col = df.columns(0);
val Row(maxValue: Int) = df.agg(max(col)).head();
```

I don't know how to combine `foreach` and the code I have so that I can get max value for every column in the dataframe. (I do not know how many columns are in the dataframe and what are the column names)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foreach` is rarely the useful solution when you want to *transform* a collection (in this case - array of column names) to something else (in this case - their maximum values). Instead, use `map` - and then pass the result to `agg`:

```
import spark.implicits._
import functions._

val df = Seq((1,3), (3, 1), (2, 2)).toDF("a", "b")

// map columns into columns representing their maximums 
val maxCols: Array[Column] = df.columns.map(max)

// aggregate all at once (have to separate first from rest due to agg's signature):
val row: Row = df.agg(maxCols.head, maxCols.tail: _*).head
```

**EDIT**: as @user8371915 reminds us, there's a much shorter version:

```
val row: Row = df.groupBy().max().head
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the name of the max column without annoying max(actul_column_name)?